# Python requests module not found error in google.auth.transport.requests

Tags: python, google-docs-api, synology

I have a Discord bot that logs all messages to a google Doc via the Google Doc api.

On my Windows PC it works just fine but when i copied it to my Synology Nas and installed all packages it gives me this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DiscordBot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth'
```

I tried reinstalling all Packages but still the Error.

Answer (score 0):

The google.auth module is missing or not installed in your Python environment on the Synology NAS.

- Activate the correct Python environment: If you are using a virtual environment for your Discord bot, make sure you activate the environment before installing the required packages.
- Install google-auth package: Open a terminal or command prompt on your Synology NAS, navigate to the location of your Discord bot script, and then install the required package using **pip install google-auth**

I've seen that using the incorrect version of Python can also cause issues when installing google-auth.  If you have multiple Python versions installed on your Synology NAS, make sure the version that has the google-auth package installed is being used to run the script.

Then lastly, after installing google-auth, check if it was installed successfully by running the following:
**pip show google-auth**

That should tell whether or not you've successfully installed the package.

Comment: Im not using a Virtual Enviroment and Yes, there are 2 Python versions installed but I cant uninstal Python 2.7 and I installed python 3 what is sed to download the package and run the script.